# Read Data from Text file & place in grid using Python

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I have text file with below data with word line by line as:

TC1

Pass

TC2

Fail

TC3

Pass

Now I would like to read the text file & import in my tkinter grid as:

Row 0      column0 column1

Row 1       Tc1     Pass

Row 2       TC2     Fail

Row 3        TC3    Pass

I have below code & just trying to read word starts with T & place the same in grid:

with open(textfile) as openfile:

```
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            i=0
            if line.startswith('T'):
                print line
                i=i+1
                Label(labelone,text=part,relief=RIDGE,width=16).grid(row=i,column=1)
```

when I run above, it gives as:

Row 0      column0 column1

Row 1       TC3

Row 2

Row 3

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things to be noted here.

1) Taking care of empty lines in the `.txt` file.

2) Iterating over to have a coupled-result like `TC1 Pass` together.

3) Appending/Inserting the coupled pair into the grid aftwards.

Approach:

Make a list that contains all the data from the `.txt` file and then iterate over to get a paired result that can later be inserted to the grid.

```
logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

# flag
nextLine = False

# list to save the lines
textList = []

for line in content:
    find_TC = line.find('TC')

    if find_TC > 0:
        nextLine = not nextLine
    else:
        if nextLine:
            pass
        else:
            textList.append(line)

print('\n')
print('Text list ..')
print(textList)

j = 0
for i in range(j, len(textList)):
    if j < len(textList):
        print(textList[j], textList[j + 1]) # Insert into the gird here instead of print
        j = j + 2
```

OUTPUT:

> Text list ..
>
> ['TC1', 'Pass', 'TC2', 'Fail', 'TC3', 'Pass']
>
> TC1 Pass
>
> TC2 Fail
>
> TC3 Pass

EDIT:

After OP's new changes in the text file

```
j = 0
for i in range(j, len(textList)):
    if j < len(textList):
        print(textList[j], textList[j + 1], textList[j+2]) # Insert into the gird here instead of print
        j = j + 3
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for more detailing

Comment: if the text file include one more data:  Text list ..

['TC1', 'Pass', 'log1', 'TC2', 'Fail', 'log 2','TC3', 'Pass' log 3] Then how the code get modified ?

Comment: @NithinDhruvah Edited the changes for it.

Comment: Hi, I would like to extend the code that, if textList[j + 1] = fail, then  I would like to get data from other text file & append it in grid. other text file contain data like numbers/ words as line by line. for example, if textList[j + 1] = fail,then get 1st line data from other text file... I have tried but couldn't solve it

Comment: @NithinDhruvah that should be asked in a new question, kindly add all the desired outputs in a new question with elaborated text files data and conditions to which the data should be fetched from another file. Cheers!